# Heritrix 3.2.0 can't find files and won't execute

Tags: java, heritrix

I'm trying to use `Heritrix 3.2.0` and following the steps provided [here](https://webarchive.jira.com/wiki/spaces/Heritrix/pages/5735587/Heritrix+Configuration) and [here2](http://crawler.archive.org/articles/user_manual/install.html). But everytime I try to execute a command like:

```
$HERITRIX_HOME/bin/heritrix --help  
$HERITRIX_HOME/bin/heritrix --webui-admin PASSWORD
```

I always get the same error:

```
ls: not possible to access 'heritrix-3.2.0/lib/*.jar': File or directory not found.
heritrix-3.2.0/bin/heritrix: line 126: heritrix-3.2.0/heritrix_out.log: File or directory not found
heritrix-3.2.0/bin/heritrix: line 127: heritrix-3.2.0/heritrix_out.log: File or directory not found
heritrix-3.2.0/bin/heritrix: line 128: heritrix-3.2.0/heritrix_out.log: File or directory not found
heritrix-3.2.0/bin/heritrix: line 129: heritrix-3.2.0/heritrix_out.log: File or directory not found
heritrix-3.2.0/bin/heritrix: line 130: heritrix-3.2.0/heritrix_out.log: File or directory not found
Qua Nov  8 00:18:07 BRST 2017 Heritrix starting (pid 6720)heritrix-3.2.0/bin/heritrix: line 140: heritrix-3.2.0/heritrix_out.log: File or directory not found
ERROR: JVM terminated without running Heritrix.
This could be due to invalid JAVA_OPTS or JMX_PORT, etc.
See heritrix_out.log for more details.
Here are its last three lines:
```

tail: couldn't open 'heritrix-3.2.0/heritrix_out.log' for reading.File or directory not found

I don't have an installed `java` which is required, like : `java -version` returns nothing, but I downloaded and unziped a `jre-8u151-linux-x64` and set this folder to `$JAVA_HOME`. May this be the problem ?

Indeed the extracted `3.2.0 version` did not come with that `heritrix_out.log` file, only the `3.1.0` version (Which worked at first and now it's no longer working).  I tried to copy that file from 3.1 to 3.2 folder but the same error remains.

#### LOG FILE from 3.1.0 folder:

```
Ter Nov  7 23:16:27 BRST 2017 Starting heritrix
Linux userName-VirtualBox 4.10.0-37-generic #41~16.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Fri Oct 6 22:42:59 UTC 2017 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
java version "1.8.0_151"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_151-b12)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.151-b12, mixed mode)
JAVA_OPTS= -Xmx256m
core file size          (blocks, -c) 0
data seg size           (kbytes, -d) unlimited
scheduling priority             (-e) 0
file size               (blocks, -f) unlimited
pending signals                 (-i) 15623
max locked memory       (kbytes, -l) 64
max memory size         (kbytes, -m) unlimited
open files                      (-n) 1024
pipe size            (512 bytes, -p) 8
POSIX message queues     (bytes, -q) 819200
real-time priority              (-r) 0
stack size              (kbytes, -s) 8192
cpu time               (seconds, -t) unlimited
max user processes              (-u) 15623
virtual memory          (kbytes, -v) unlimited
file locks                      (-x) unlimited
Oracle Corporation Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment 1.8.0_151-b12
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: sun/security/tools/KeyTool
    at org.archive.crawler.Heritrix.useAdhocKeystore(Heritrix.java:438)
    at org.archive.crawler.Heritrix.instanceMain(Heritrix.java:319)
    at org.archive.crawler.Heritrix.main(Heritrix.java:189)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: sun.security.tools.KeyTool
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:335)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 3 more
```